# Open all links in an iframe in a new tab (same domain)

Tags: javascript, iframe

There are loads of similar posts on this topic, but I tried all and none worked for what I'd like to do.

I've got an iframe which leads other pages on my domain.

```
<iframe src="test/index.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" id="iframe" name="iframe"></iframe>
```

Note: I can't change the code of the pages inside the iframe.

Using jQuery, I'd like to open *all* links of 'text/index.html' in a new tab. How can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a `function` in the `iframe` like this:

```
document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.targetFunction();
```

Now, you can do something like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
var links = (iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document).getElementsByTagName('a');
```

and then you can iterate the links and open them in new tabs/windows, using `window.open`. Some browsers will not allow you to do this due to security constraint. Now, if the `iframe` has some messaging with other windows, then you might want to read this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Finally, if none of these are available, you can just simply send a request to the page which is displayed in the `iframe` and when you receive the HTML, parse it, find the links and open them using `window.open`.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping! Unfortunately, I'm a complete JS novice. Any chance you can show me how I can implement the option that's most likely to work in all browsers?

Comment: @Kai I am always writing code which should work in all browsers. See the way the document is got (iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document). However, if it does not work in a browser, then it needs to be fixed. But the testing is of course your job. I have given you three possible solutions. The first is to directly access the iframe's DOM if you are allowed. The second is to communicate it using postMessage if the page in the iframe supports that. The third is to extract the whole page and parse it as a text. I believe this should answer your question.

Comment: @Kai if you have difficulties using the solution(s) I have given, due to a lack of Javascript knowledge, then you might want to take a look at some tutorials of the language, especially Douglas Crockford's videos, they helped me  learn the language in a few hours when I was a novice in it. So, if you have difficulties applying the solution, then you have other questions. Try to answer them yourself and if you do not succeed, then search for the answer on the internet and if there is still no success, ask another question on SO.