# Is it possible to use XMLHttpRequest to download all files in a directory from a URL?

Tags: javascript, http, sockets, xmlhttprequest

[image]

I'm working on a project to create a web-client to connect to a server with Xmlhttprequest and download all the files from the server. I've been succeeded in downloading a specific file. I wonder Is there any way to download a whole folder ( folder shown in the image above)
and zip them ?

Here is my code :

```
let host = "https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224w/slides/";

function reqListener(data) {
    // console.log(data.currentTarget.responseText)
    // if (data.length)
    console.log(data)
    // console.log(data.currentTarget.responseText.length)
    req.abort();
}

const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // document.body.innerHTML = req.response;

        var downloadURL = URL.createObjectURL(req.response);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.style = "display:none";
        a.href = downloadURL;
        // a.download = "index1.html";
        a.click();
    }
}

req.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
req.open("GET", host);
req.responseType = "blob";
// req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.send();
```

Comment: `a whole folder` ... if the server can send the list of files in a folder, then yes

Comment: The obvious solution is to parse the text of the index to get the list of files and download each individually. Allowing to download the directory in one go would imply some work for the server managers and I suppose they'd advertised that possibility to students.

Comment: From your description it appears there are no cross-domain problems.  So you could greatly simplify the process by loading the file list page into a hidden iframe and then programmatically click on the download links. No ajax required. See: [Open all links in an iframe in a new tab (same domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52745315/open-all-links-in-an-iframe-in-a-new-tab-same-domain)